# Search module doesn't work in Orchard CMS 1.6?

Tags: search, module, content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm using Orchard CMS 1.6.
I have added a Search Widget on the Asidesecond zone.
When I went back to my Website I didn't have any input for searching.

So I have created a Custom form and I added a Search Part to it. Then I added a input field.
I have created another Widget in the AsideSecond Zone which contains my Custom Search Form.
When I went back to my WebSite I tried to enter a word in the input and then I pressed Enter key : nothing happened, no search results displaying.

I have already Check for the indexes and the contents to included in the search.
Besides, the search module doesn't display any button to launch the search. Is it normal ?

Thanks for your answers.
Franck

Comment: Search works just fine in 1.6. It's the custom form thing that gets me confused: why are you doing that? Why not just use the search widget?

Comment: It's works fine right now. The Widget part was missing in the Search Form Content Type. So, what I still don't understand. Why there isn't any button near the Search Widget ? The Admin Content Search have a button, why the Search Widget doesn't have one ? Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's works fine right now. The Widget part was missing in the Search Form Content Type. So, what I still don't understand. Why there isn't any button near the Search Widget ? The Admin Content Search have a button, why the Search Widget doesn't have one ? Any Idea ?

Comment: It does have a button. What theme are you using?

Comment: You should ask the author of that theme then.